# JSF 2.0 Components

Tags: java, jsf

Does anyone know of any good resources for JSF 2.0 components? I'm trying to develop a file upload component to teach myself JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0 but I'm having a hard time finding resources. I've been looking at the Mojarra 2.0.2 source but it seems like a lot of their stuff is still using JSF 1.x concepts. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm needing standard JSF components rather than composite components. Can anyone confirm that for me?

Comment: Composite components are built up of standard components with the aim to remove the need to repeat the same bunch of components again and again. The JSF standard implementation doesn't have any standard component for file upload.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking but I wasn't completely sure. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Be super cool and make a JSF2.0 component incorporating SWFUpload (http://swfupload.org/) - it's awesome - and then GitHub/GoogleSource it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Last week at the Sun forum someone has posted an example of a custom JSF 2.0 file upload component, but it is built up on Apache Commons FileUpload API and the code has here and there several flaws, but it may be enough information to start with. Be careful though, some of those flaws are serious: [JavaServer Faces - Creating JSF 2.0 File Upload Component](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421845)

By a coincidence, I was lately also playing with the idea around a JSF 2.0 file upload component in combination with the new Servlet 3.0 multipart support for a new article at my blog. It's only hard to figure what's the *best* way to create a JSF 2.0 custom component (a `@FacesComponent`), Google reveals a little, only [this blog of Jim Driscoll](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/10/09/jsf-2-custom-java-components-and-ajax-behaviors) is somewhat useful. Further it's nowhere explained in the Java EE 6 tutorial and even the JSF 2.0 specification tells nothing about it.

**Update:** I got it to work, but there is one major disadvantage: I can't make use of the Servlet 3.0 `@MultipartConfig` annotation to specify the upload location and the max file size. This get activated only if set on a `Servlet`, not on a `Filter`. As the `FacesServlet` is declared **`final`** and the JSF provides no facility to have another `Servlet` to process the request before the `FacesServlet` kicks in, I don't see any clean ways to make use of the annotation. Normally the upload location is to be configured in the annotation, but this is easy workaroundable by using `Part#getInputStream()` instead of `Part#write()`. The max file size is in no way configureable without the annotation, so you'll have to live with "unlimited size uploads" and the fact that you can only validate it when the upload is complete (which may on the other hand be an advantage, because the enduser would otherwise face an ugly HTTP 500 error).

**Update 2:**: here's the blog: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend taking a look into **PrimeFaces**: http://primefaces.org/

It is a component suite built for JSF (and specifically supports JSF 2.0) under open-source license, uses YahooUI under the covers, and supports your file upload scenario as well.

Comment: I am using primefaces with pretty good success in jsf 2, but the upload component is shaky.  You can see the discussions in the forums 
http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2626&p=12545&hilit=fileupload#p12545
http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2227&p=12469&hilit=fileupload#p12469

So while you can use primefaces for other jsf2 stuff, you will probably need to look elsewhere for an upload component.

Answer (score 0):

The standard JSF components do not include a file upload component. This component is usually provided in in 3rd-party JSF component libraries such as myfaces, icefaces, etc...

At the moment I don't know of any JSF 2.0 component libraries that are ready yet (other than the spec standard) so I'm unaware of any file upload components that are JSF 2.0 ready.

Answer (score -1):

I have some examples here : http://mcatr.blogspot.com/search/label/JSF
hope it helps